# Additional command on Husky Hooks fail

Tags: git, npm, githooks, husky, git-husky

I am using `husky` and `commitLint` to check the commit messages in one of the repo's I work.

**package.json**

```json
"husky": {
  "hooks": {
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
    "commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS"
  }
}
```

pretty straightforward. However, as I don't wanna create a barrier for the less experienced developers of my team I wanna run a CLI to help them format their commit message IF the hook "commit-msg" fails because of bad formatting.

So, I tried the following `"commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS &> /dev/null || npx git-cz"`
and it executes the second command, but it also closes the cli right after running it.

So, any idea how to implement such thing ?

Comment: Good question, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @ridvanaltun unfortunately not. I had to change the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with this:

```
"husky": {
  "hooks": {
    "prepare-commit-msg": "exec < /dev/tty && git cz --hook || true"
  }
}
```

[source](https://github.com/commitizen/cz-cli#husky)

Comment: doesnt really work as it runs the CLI regardless the commit message is good or not.

Comment: you could validate the commit message directly with commitlint. Check if this is useful for you [commitlint-usage](https://github.com/mpielvitori/commitlint-usage)